# MSSQL-Query: Return result if all values in column are null

Tags: sql-server

Table1

```
NoteNr | TransactionID
----------------------
4711   | NULL
4711   | 123
4812   | NULL
4913   | 444
4610   | NULL
4610   | NULL
```

I want to have a query which produces the following result

```
4812 NULL
4610 NULL
```

So if any entry of the same `NoteNr` has  a value in its `TransactionID` Column, the `NoteNr` should not be in the result of the query. The Resultset should only contain NoteNrs, if all entries of the `NoteNr` has no value in its `TransactionID` Column (NULL)

Comment: What queries have you attempted to achieve this?

Comment: @DKyleo tried an approach with `MIN(CASE WHEN TransactionID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0` but since in NoteNr `4711` is one entry NULL, this is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM   Table1 t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (   SELECT 1
                      FROM   Table1
                      WHERE  NoteNr = t.NoteNr
                             AND TransactionId IS NOT NULL );
```

Comment: This needs a DISTINCT to return the same results in question.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
select NoteNr, NULL From (
       select NoteNr, sum(TransactionID) as c From [table] group by NoteNr
) as t1 where t1.c IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

USE CAN USE CTE to achieve this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY NoteNr  ORDER BY NoteNr)Rownum FROM #TEMP a   WHERE TransactionID IS NULL AND NoteNr NOT IN (SELECT NoteNr FROM #TEMP WHERE TransactionID IS NOT NULL)
)
SELECT NoteNr,TransactionID FROM CTE WHERE Rownum=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help.

```
SELECT NoteNr
    ,TransactionID
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT NoteNr
        ,TransactionID
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY NoteNr ORDER BY NoteNr
            ) AS rowno
    ) AS main
WHERE rowno = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most efficient way to avoid the grouping needed to remove duplicates:

```
Select notenr, Null as TransactionId from @table1
except
select notenr, Null as TransactionId from @table1 where TransactionID is not null
```